# RateLimited writes in DynamoDB

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

There are ways to Rate-Limit the scan operation in DynamoDB like : https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3VAYQIZ3Q0ZVW/Rate-Limited-Scans-in-Amazon-DynamoDB

I was wondering is there a way to do that for writing also. Suppose, I have to update a table in Dynamo with ~200 entries and I want to do that so that my threshold for writing i.e. 1 entry per sec is not violated.

The code for rate limited reading is something like :

```
    do {
    // Let the rate limiter wait until our desired throughput "recharges"
    rateLimiter.acquire(permitsToConsume);

    // Do the scan
    ScanRequest scan = new ScanRequest()
        .withTableName("ProductCatalog")
        .withLimit(100)
        .withReturnConsumedCapacity(ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL)
        .withExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey);
    ScanResult result = dynamodb.scan(scan);
    exclusiveStartKey = result.getLastEvaluatedKey();

    // Account for the rest of the throughput we consumed, 
    // now that we know how much that scan request cost 
    double consumedCapacity = result.getConsumedCapacity().getCapacityUnits();
    permitsToConsume = (int)(consumedCapacity - 1.0);
    if(permitsToConsume <= 0) {
        permitsToConsume = 1;
    }

    // Process results here
    processYourResults(result);

} while (exclusiveStartKey  != null);
```

Please note that the permits to consume are updated based upon the capacity used by scan operation. So my question is how to update them for the write operation ?

Additionally, If I know that my write operation is 1 consumed capacity, would it be safe to update the permits by 1 in the loop ? (It's an assumption)

Comment: Essentially, just replace the scan operation with your write. It's simply a `while` loop that [waits](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) every iteration if necessary.

Comment: @zapl I have updated the question. Could you suggest if my assumption is safe ?

Comment: If you know that it's 1 then it's safe to assume that 1 is correct, since you know. On the other hand, if you just guess that it's 1 it's not safe since you're just guessing :) All the requests are AFAIK able to return you the consumed capacity: e.g. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/PutItemRequest.html#withReturnConsumedCapacity%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ReturnConsumedCapacity%29

Answer (score 3):

An easy option that comes to mind is to either use SQS in front of all of your writes, or use SQS as a 'overflow buffer' as soon as you get the first threshold error.

You would then have a background process that runs continusously and moves records from SQS to DynamoDB at a pre-defined pace that is below your max threshold. This design pattern works particularly well, and is cost-effecient, when you have spikes in the writes but don't want to pay for that higher capacity 24x7 with dynamodb.

The benefit of this is the client submitting the records (writes), won't be block while you wait for the retries to happen; SQS can ingest writes at almost any speed for no additional cost, i.e. you pay per message, not the message rate.

Comment: Your suggestion is really great. I will try using it in the future, for now my writes are limited and there is no reason that they could have any spike. But they will in future, then I would use SQS.